# How Do I Wrap A DependencyProperty of An Element Contained Inside A UserControl?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

With a UserControl containing a Path like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Path x:Name="path1" >
        <Path.Data>
            <GeometryGroup>
                <EllipseGeometry x:Name="ellipse1" ... />
                <EllipseGeometry x:Name="ellipse2" ... />
            </GeometryGroup>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</UserControl>
```

How can I expose properties of Path such as Fill or Stroke as properties of the usercontrol so that I can declare bindings on them.

```
<MineAllMine:MyUserControl ... DataContext="{Binding MyMasterPlan}" Fill="{Binding Colour}" />
```

I tried wrapping the properties by declaring new DependencyProperties something like:

```
public class MyUserControl:UserControl{
    ...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FillProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Fill", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(Path.FillProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue));

    public Brush Fill
    {
        get { return path1.Fill; }
        set { path1.Fill = value; }
    }
    ...
}
```

Alas, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the Path.Fill to a DP already on the UserControl such as `Background` or `Foreground` or define a new one that you can bind to such as `PathFill`. The end result is similar to using a TemplateBinding within a ControlTemplate except you're using a RelativeSource binding back to the parent UserControl.

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PathFillProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(...);

    public Brush PathFill
    {
        get { return GetValue(...); }
        set { SetValue(...); }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Path Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=PathFill">
...
</Path>
```

Comment: This is what I've tried to do by declaring a FillProperty in the code behind of my UserControl, I then just tried to get it to pass the binding on to the Path path1's Fill property but this doesn't work.  I'm looking for a way I can convert the binding on MyUserControl.FillProperty into a binding on the Path.FillProperty of path1.

Comment: This is a correct answer but i normally would name the UserControl and use an `ElementName`-binding which is shorter and might be computationally less complex. (You do not need to specify the mode (`FindAncestor`) of the `RelativeSource` either if you set the `AncestorType` by the way)